# How to automate putty commands when connection is through ssh?

Tags: shell-script, ssh, putty

Two files are there. I want to run cmds.txt cmd in ssh port connectivity . how to run txt file with putty.

if suppose this is a sv.bat (batch file)

Inside batch file there is a txt file with cmds.

```
start C:\USERS\putty\putty.exe -ssh 10.15.12.12  -m C:\USERS\cmds.txt
```

cmds.txt

```
login
password
```

Comment: `putty` is a Windows program which is completely off-topic here.  You can ask a car mechanics how to use tools to replace the muffler but not how to fix those tools.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Unix or Linux.

Answer (score 1):

After creating txt file, you will have to create a [BAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) file or type it in the CMD prompt:

- `ssh.cmd`
- `@echo on` [to see what's going on]
- [Navigate to your PuTTY installation.] `cd C:\Program Files\Putty`
- Start `putty.exe -ssh [domain name] -l [username] -pw [password] -m [the directory of the .txt file you created which contains the codes you want to be executed]`

---

If `-m` option does not work for you, You should use `plink.exe` (a command-line interface to the PuTTY back ends) and not `putty.exe`

```
-m file   read remote command(s) from file
```

You will get that from the [PuTTY download page](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)

Comment: How can I use variables in txt file inside code?